# Swift UIControlState.Selected remain selected?

Tags: swift, button, ibaction, control-state

I have 3 buttons which are provided to the user to select which category they wish to see.

They are defined as the below:

```
 //outlets
@IBOutlet weak var ChineseButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var IndianButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var MexicanButton: UIButton!
```

I have the below actions on these buttons (changing the original image button to a greyed out version):

//actions

```
@IBAction func ChineseButtonPressed(sender: UIButton)
{

    ChineseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "chinese.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    ChineseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "chinese.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
    IndianButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "grey-indian.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    MexicanButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "grey-mexican.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
@IBAction func EightFacedButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
         IndianButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "indian.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
IndianButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "indian.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
    ChineseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "grey-chinese.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    MexicanButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "grey-mexican.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

@IBAction func TweleveFacedButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    MexicanButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "mexican.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
MexicanButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "mexican.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
    ChineseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "grey-chinese.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    IndianButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "grey-indian.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)   
}
```

This action function also determines the UIControlState, i have another button which, once clicked will take you to another page but needed to understand which button was selected.

I tried the below however it doesn't seem to recognise which button was selected?

```
 @IBAction func GenerateButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if ChineseButton.selected == true{
            println("Chinese button was selected")
        }
```

I am new to swift so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting the button, you are just changing the images.

First, you can simplify all your code and set the images once, greyed out for normal, and colored for selected state:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    MexicanButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "mexican.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    MexicanButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "grey-mexican.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
    ChineseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "grey-chinese.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    ChineseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "chinese.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
    IndianButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "grey-indian.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    IndianButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "indian.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected) 
}
```

You can configure this on Storyboard too changing `Image` at the different `State Configs` of the icon:

[image]

Then, on each action you can simply select the button, and the correct image will be shown (you can use the same action for all buttons):

```
@IBAction func AnyButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    // Deselect all buttons but the pressed one
    for button in [ChineseButton, IndianButton, MexicanButton] {
        button.selected = sender === button
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. I have updated my code with the above however now it is only showing 1 button so i think i have gone wrong somewhere. 

Am i replacing the content from all my action functions with:  
'// Deselect all buttons but the pressed one
    for button in [ChineseButton, IndianButton, MexicanButton] {
        button.selected = sender === button
    }'?

Comment: All your buttons can call the same action, no need for a custom action for each button if they all do the same. Maybe you replaced your `viewDidLoad` method? You have to add the lines, not replace what you had.

Comment: Thanks I have got this to work now. The only issue i am now facing is if the user wants to change from Chinese to Indian it won't allow it as the Chinese button is already selected.

Comment: Clicking on the Indian will de-select the Chinese and select the Indian. Isn't that ok?

Comment: Hi, Yes that is perfect. I think I an error which meant this wasn't working but all is good now. Thank you very much for your help!!